# MobaXterm x server forwarding with sudo

Tags: ssh, ibmhttpserver, mobaxterm

I need to execute `ikeyman` on an IBM HTTP Server. Since I don't want to install a full blown UI on the server, I used MobaXterm with x forwarding for the Windows workstations. When executed as regular user (e.g. `/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/ikeyman`) it works. For corresponding permissions in certain folders, `ikeyman` need to run as root:

```
sudo -i
/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/ikeyman
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:217)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:547)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:431)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:396)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:200)
        at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.KeymanFrame.<init>(KeymanFrame.java)
        at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.KeymanFrame.<init>(KeymanFrame.java)
        at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.Ikeyman.main(Ikeyman.java)
```

Not working:

- `sudo DISPLAY=localhost:10.0 /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/ikeyman` (the `DISPLAY` value was copied from the regular user)
- [`xauth add $(xauth -f /home/user/.Xauthority list | tail -1 )`](https://blog.mobatek.net/post/how-to-keep-X11-display-after-su-or-sudo/)
- ````
  export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
  /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/ikeyman```
  ````

Comment: Would have been quicker to learn bin/gskcapicmd syntax. Ikeyman is really an abomination.

But do you have output from any of the attempts that actually set DISPLAY?
Do you have an invocation that works with xeyes/xterm but not ikeyman?

I generally find ssh -X root@localhost or ssh -Y root@localhost to work more reliably then trying to manually setup the env to survive across the sudo.  Assuming PermitRootLogin is not blocked.